# pytesseract image_to_string function not accurate at all

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

My code

```py
for index, img in enumerate(data): # data is list of base64 decoded strings
    b64 = base64.b64decode(bytes(img[22:], encoding='utf-8'))
    raw = BytesIO(b64)
    im = Image.open(raw).convert('LA')
    pixels = im.load()
    width, height = im.size
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if pixels[x, y][0] > 100: pixels[x, y] = (255, 255)
            else: pixels[x, y] = (0, 255)
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='tessedit_char_whitelist=1234567890plus?'))
```

My Image:
[image]

Output:
`Te Ys`
What I can do to make this better, I tried to use every psm from 0 to 13 and -c flag in config

Comment: help is still needed

Comment: give a little padding to the image.

Comment: have you tried simple thresholding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked fine for me but spaces were not detected.

```
    img = ~cv2.imread("18.png",0)
    rows,cols = img.shape[:2]
    # M = np.float32([[1,0,25],[0,1,15]])
    # img = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols*2,rows*2),borderValue=(255,255,255))
    custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="1234567890plus?"'# -c preserve_interword_spaces=1'
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config=custom_oem_psm_config))
```

Output:

```
18plus16?
```